# Ограничить тип данных при помощи дженериков

Tags: java, groovy

Есть класс который получает именованные значения и может формировать из этих значений контрольную сумму. Как ограничить тип данных, для значения `value`, чтобы можно было использовать только числовые данные при помощи дженериков?

```
import java.util.zip.CRC32


class DictionaryInteger {

Map<String, ? extends Number> map = [:]


void add(String name, value) {

map.put(name, value)
}

String MD5() {
def text = map.values().inject('') {result, value -> result + value}

def crc = CRC32.newInstance()
crc.update(text.bytes)

(crc.value as String).bytes.encodeHex()
}
}

def p = new DictionaryInteger()

p.add('1', 2344)
p.add('ter', 32423)

p.MD5()
```

Comment: А чем не подходит просто `Double/Float`? Без `extends`

Comment: @AntonSorokin, хочу использовать не только `Double` или  `Float`, а и то и то сразу. Тоесть числовые типы, но не строки

Comment: @AntonSorokin, можно просто перегрузку методов сделать для разных типов данных. Но не пойму почему не срабатывает с `extends`

Comment: ПРи использовании Double сможете туда и int и float запихивать, все автоконвертироваться будет